# create this shape using css3 and html

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image: css3 button]

This is demo image how to create this button in css3.
please help me anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny exercise, something like this?

```css
div {
    height: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: rgb(231,76,60);
    position: relative;
}
div:before {
    content: '';
    height: 16px;
    width: 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgb(221,221,221);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    background: #DDDDDD;
}
div#oval{
    background: #E74C3C;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
div#window{
    background: #DDDDDD;
    height: 16px;
    width: 7px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="oval">
    <div id="window"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#red {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#gray {
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="red">
  <div id="gray"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    body{
      background-color:black;
    }
    .eye-wrap {
      position: absolute;
      top: -5em;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
     }
    .eye {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      height: 110px;
      width: 80px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: red;
      overflow: hidden;
     }
    .in-eye {
      position: absolute;
      height: 55px;
      width: 45px;
      left: 15px;
      bottom: 0;
      top: -35px;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="eye-wrap left-eye">
      <div class="eye">
      <div class="in-eye"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

using CSS3 only.Please check out this [pen](http://codepen.io/vinrav/pen/WbrxYM).

Comment: I know, it is not good enough be in this competion. It is provided as starting point for you. But all the pros seems to be interested in your question, getting yourself better and better answer. You should opt  @Leo's Answer. It is realy good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on how to create a button similar to the one you posted an image of. I added a simple animation effect to the button, but if it is not what you are looking for you could always remove it.

```css
/*CSS Code*/

#button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F76B4F;
  border-radius: 14px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  /*The transition effect that smooths the animations*/
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
}

/*When the mouse is hovering over the button*/
#button:hover {
  background-color: #C95B44;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*When the button is being pressed*/
#button:active {
  background-color: #A33C27;
  height: 38px;
}

#push {
  height: 8px;
  width: 0px;
}

#center {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML Code -->

<div id="button">
  <div id="push"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```